# How to see the fields which are used in a Visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, email-template, visualforce-template

Have a visualforce email template for details on Opportunity closed won - I want to check which fields are being pulled through into the template from the Opportunity record.

Where do I go to find this information as it does not show when going into the email template. Any help will be much appreciated

This is what I am see when I try edit the template
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field(s) On EmailTemplate To Determine Merged Objects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154045/fields-on-emailtemplate-to-determine-merged-objects)

Comment: Hi Swetha, don't think it does unfortunately.

This is all I am seeing when I try edit the template. Should I be looking elsewhere? an APEX controller?

<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {font-family: Arial; size: 12pt;}
    </style>
<c:NewSalesOpportunityEmail opportunityId="{!relatedTo.Id}" opportunity="{!relatedTo}"/>

</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this. You will have to edit the record and then look for tags like `{!relatedTo.}` to figure the fields referenced in the Email Template.

Comment: Hi Mohith, thanks for coming back to me. That's fine to do but I'm not seeing any of that when I try and edit the template. Is there another section I should be looking at?

Comment: Screenshot may be what you see?

Comment: thanks Mohith, I've added above. Sorry, completely new to this. I can't see in the components either where it refers to any field

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the Visualforce Component called NewSalesOpportunityEmail. All the fields you have in the template will be shown there, or in any child Visualforce Components referenced in that component.